# How to deal with the following query using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a School Management System in Laravel 5.7. I have two tables.

1. students
2. monthly_fees

What i want is to select the **months** with value **1** by joining the **monthly_fees** table with **students** and by giving a condition on **students** table. To make it simple. I wanna do the following query in Eloquent way.

```
SELECT * FROM `students` 
INNER JOIN `monthly_fees` ON `monthly_fees`.`student_id` = `students`.`id` 
WHERE `students`.`class` = 'whatever'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do a join at all. With Laravel you can simply eager-load and filter the results by the relationship table (**The eloquent way**):

```
Students::whereHas('MonthlyFees', function ($query) {
     $query->where('months', 1);
})->get();
```

By doing this you would **only** get the Student results where the months column is equal to 1. Then simply filter through the results in a blade view as you normally would. Hope this helps!

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Student::MonthlyFees()

Comment: That's not quite right! `MonthlyFees` references a relationship that you must create! `whereHas` searches results within the relationship, this means you can filter your results based off of the relationship column. However, if you want the filter results from the parent relationship i.e `Students` then you do not need `whereHas` at all... Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query:

```
DB::select(`students.*`, `monthly_fees.*`)
    ->from(`students`)
    ->join(`monthly_fees`, function($join) {
        $join->on(`monthly_fees.student_id`, `=`, `students.id`);
    })
    ->where(`students.class`, `=`, 'whatever')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Eloquent way would be to do something like the following:

```php
Student::with('monthly_fees')->where('class', 'whatever')->get();
```

That will return all Students belonging to that class with their monthly fees. You'll obviously need to make sure you have setup the correct relationships on your `Student` and `MonthlyFee` models.